# Google reCaptcha test without frontend

Tags: java, spring, recaptcha

Im trying to integrate google reCaptcha into our backend. I'm getting always `invalid-input-response`. I'm using testing secret key, post or get doesn't matter. **It is said it will accept any response, but do they think any response at all or any user generated response?** It seams that I need to create proper page with captcha to test it. Not just some `curl http://localhost:8080/app/register --data "g-recaptcha-response=aaaa"`

Is the `g-recaptcha-response` some identifier of "captcha try" as there is no text to be send, that user enters, in case of the new "I'm not robot" captcha.

Answer (score 1):

You understand that the purpose of recaptcha is to force human interaction? google recaptcha wil prompt the human user for some input (lke identify objects in pictures) and save the result in a cookie. without the interactive part, there is no way to test the feature

Comment: And what about `With the following test keys, you will always get No CAPTCHA and all verification requests will pass.` stated [here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq). It looks like the code generated by reCaptcha in frontend needs to be sent to BE even with testing keys, probably they are validating if the captcha verification request has been made at all, but they do not care about the value returned or what. With "all verification requests will pass" do they mean frontend request, or requests to google api? Seams the first is correct.